# Count number of cases reaching a given deadline

Tags: python, pandas, date, group-by

I have a dataframe similar to below:

| Case ID | D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Dec 2022 | Feb 2023 | May 2023 | Jun 2024 |
| B | Jul 2020 | May 2023 | Aug 2024 |  |
| C | May 2019 | Jul 2020 | Dec 2021 |  |
| D | Jul 2020 | Mar 2021 | Apr 2021 | Aug 2024 |
| E | May 2019 | May 2023 | Aug 2024 |  |
| F | Dec 2022 | Feb 2023 | May 2023 | Aug 2024 |
| G | Dec 2022 | Feb 2023 | May 2023 | Aug 2024 |

And I would like to have a **dataframe** with all dates (from min(date) of above dataframe to max(date)) as index and then number of cases who have a deadline(i.e. Dx) for a given date.  So, visually I am expecting something similar to below:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Please add some sample data as text for us to reproduce your task.

Comment: do you want to plot your data like in the image or do you just need the data aggregation as a dataframe?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far, such as using `groupby`?

Comment: Thank you @Rabinzel, I have now fixed the data format. I would like to have data aggregation as dataframe please and the image is just to illustrate how should the dataframe look like when plotted (grouped by different deadline names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came to a solution, not sure if it is the most straight-forward way, but I think it works.

```
# reshape data from wide to long and add a column "has_deadline" as marker. 
df1 = df.set_index('Case ID').stack().reset_index(name='dates').rename(columns={'level_1': 'deadlines'})
df1['has_deadline'] = 1

# we need to create a new index which includes every single combination for each Case, deadline and date
# Then reindex the dataframe (missing values will be filled with NaN)
df1 = df1.set_index(['deadlines', 'dates', 'Case ID'])
new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df1.index.levels)
df1 = df1.reindex(new_idx)

# Now we need to sum each row to get the sum of all cases for each deadline and date
# also sort the index chronological
df1 = df1.unstack(level=2).sum(axis=1).unstack('deadlines').sort_index(key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format="%b %Y"))
print(df1)
```

Output `df1`:

```
deadlines   D1   D2   D3   D4
dates                        
May 2019   2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
Jul 2020   2.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
Mar 2021   0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
Apr 2021   0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
Dec 2021   0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
Dec 2022   3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
Feb 2023   0.0  3.0  0.0  0.0
May 2023   0.0  2.0  3.0  0.0
Jun 2024   0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
Aug 2024   0.0  0.0  2.0  3.0
```

Plot:

```
# plot each column
for col in df1.columns:
    tmp = df1.loc[df1[col].ne(0), col]
    plt.scatter(x=tmp.index, y=tmp, label=col)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('Dates')
plt.ylabel('No. of Cases')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
```

[image]